# How to list files given path with poorly escaped Windows separator

Tags: ruby

I'm attempting to do this:

```
Dir["c:\temp\*.*"]
```

but that is failing.  I understand why, but I seem to lack the Ruby prowess to work around it.

I am given the path in a variable and otherwise have no control over it.  Nor do I know the contents ahead of time.

Is there a way to make Dir function with double quoted strings that are poorly escaped? Alternatively, how does one take a variable with the apparent contents

```
"c:\temp\*.*"
```

and convert it into

```
'c:/temp/*.*'
```

This problem at the core seems to be how to potentially escape a string that should have been escaped but now is not.

The end result is I am not able to use the given string to do this as conceptually simple as `puts()` or `Dir[]`.

If given `'c:\temp\*.*'` then I have no problem.  I can fix that:

```
foo = 'c:\temp\*.*'.gsub('\\', '/')
```

If given `"c:\\\\temp\\\\*.*"` then I have no problem.  I can fix that:

```
foo = "c:\\temp\\*.*".gsub("\\", "/")
```

However, I am passed neither of those, but rather `"c:\\temp\\*.*"`.  This string contains a TAB and a second undefined escape. It is this that I can't fix in a general way.

Even if I knew the contents ahead of time I am stumped on how to properly escape and transform this.  I should add that I am not a ruby programmer at the moment so maybe there is some simple method to deal with this that I am not aware of.

I tried a bunch of stuff like:

```
"c:\temp\*.*".gsub("\t", "/t")
```

which gets me part of the way, but since the actual contents of the string are not known to me ahead of time this is a little wonky.  Further, if the escape character is not valid as in `\\*` then I am also in a jam. So this also fails:

```
"c:\temp\*.*".gsub("\t", "/t").gsub("\*", "/*")
```

Comment: The additional information added should have been in the question from the start. This now seems like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/153968). Do you have control over the creation of the string? If so, fix the problem there, as it's going to cause a lot more work downstream to clean it up.

Comment: I don't have control of the input.  As I said, it is something passed to me.  I agree that the additional information makes the problem more apparent and that is why I added it.  I believe though that in my initial presentation of the issue the problem was stated as related to poor escaping.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Is there a way to make Dir function with double quoted strings that are poorly escaped?

No.

Garbage in, garbage out. There is no Rumpelstiltskin routine that returns gold when given trash.

Ruby auto-converts forward-slashes in filenames/paths to reverse-slashes when running on Windows. Simply make it a habit of using forward, *nix-style, slashes and you'll be fine.

From the [IO documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/IO.html):

> Ruby will convert pathnames between different operating system conventions if possible. For instance, on a Windows system the filename "`/gumby/ruby/test.rb`" will be opened as "`\gumby\ruby\test.rb`". When specifying a Windows-style filename in a Ruby string, remember to escape the backslashes:

```
"c:\\gumby\\ruby\\test.rb"
```

---

> I don't have "c:\temp" I have "c:\temp" as input

In a properly defined Windows path you should see:

```
'c:' + '\temp' + '\*.*' # => "c:\\temp\\*.*"
```

Note that the single-quotes are treating "`\t`" as an escaped-escape + "t". Your source for the variable is creating the string improperly by using double-quotes:

```
'c:' + "\temp" + "\*.*" # => "c:\temp*.*"
```

If you have `"\t"`, you have a TAB character. It's possible to change it to an escaped-T using:

```
"c:\temp" # => "c:\temp"
"c:\temp"[2] # => "\t"
"c:\temp"[2].ord # => 9

'\t' # => "\\t"

"c:\temp".sub("\t", '\t') # => "c:\\temp"
```

The next problem is what to do when you have a String containing "*" to convert it to "`\*`". There's no way to search for "`\*`" because that's the same as "`*`" as seen above:

```
"\*.*" # => "*.*"
```

But, since "`*.*`" is a fairly specific "anything" wildcard, maybe simply searching for and replacing that pattern would work:

```
"c:\temp\*.*".gsub('*.*', '\\*.*') # => "c:\temp\\*.*"
```

or:

```
"c:\temp\*.*".gsub('*.*', '/*.*') # => "c:\temp/*.*"
```

Back to dealing with "`\t"` and putting it all together... I'd start with:

```
"c:\temp\*.*".gsub("\t", '\t').gsub('*.*', '/*.*') # => "c:\\temp/*.*"
"c:\temp\*.*".gsub("\t", '/t').gsub('*.*', '/*.*') # => "c:/temp/*.*"
```

You'll have to figure out what to do if you have something like:

```
c:/dir/file*.*
```

where they mean they want all files *starting with* `file`. Since you're seeing ambiguous inputs it seems the input routine needs to be more rigorous to not allow reversed-slashes.

Comment: Yes, I understand the documentation.  I don't have "c:\\temp"  I have "c:\temp" as input..

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer "No, not possible".  No need to be condescending though.  I had hoped my initial response to your suggestion that I "RTFM" would have suggested as much.  I specifically mention in my question almost all the details in your answer including the observation that I am given a "tab" character.  Thanks for using upper case to point that out, I did as well.  Your answer also uses the examples I quote in my question.  You basically said "no, not possible" then quoted my question back to me as if you had done something clever.

Comment: We use upper case to mark keys/characters like TAB and ENTER to differentiate them from tab-stops and such. Nobody is being condescending, nor did I ever suggest RTFM. Also, I tried to systematically show the problem and fixes. That's to help others, not just you, as SO is mostly about helping the world, not just the individual. You're welcome to not select the answer if you don't like it. I'm trying to help but whether you feel it is a solution is up to you. Down voting and selecting doesn't seem sensible. Remove the selection and I'll delete the answer.

Comment: Your answer is correct and I marked it thus.  However, the bulk of it just provides the same facts and insights as the question and adds little additional value in my opinion. Quoting the documentation is a misdirection.  The question was never about how to properly specify a windows path, but rather what to do in the event that one was given a path known to be improperly escaped.  I do appreciate your input and the time you took to help me though.  I am sure I have given an impression to the contrary and I apologize for that.

Comment: If you put in a minor edit I will remove my downvote.  I agree it was petty of me.